# Generic connection bulder

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've to create an embedded monitoring for existing application, these applications are using both `Entity Framework` and `ADO`. I have to check if the connections strings are good, and I'm doing it this way actually:

```
if (c.ConnectionString.Contains("metadata"))
{
    using (var connection = new EntityConnection(c.ConnectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            isWorking = true;
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (EntityException)
        {
            // Le catch n'a pas de raison d'être, la variable étant à false par défaut    
        }
    }
}
else
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(c.ConnectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            isWorking = true;
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (SqlException)
        {
            // Le catch n'a pas de raison d'être, la variable étant à false par défaut    
        }
    }
}
```

But I've a lot of redundancy. How can I develop this thing to only got the try catch one time and not one for `Entity` an one for `SQL` ?

The `connections strings` are actually retrieved with `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings`

Thank you.

Comment: To make this easy to extend you should encapsulate the different types of connections into their own classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[EntityConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entityclient.entityconnection(v=vs.110).aspx) and [SqlConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.110).aspx) both inherit from [DbConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnection(v=vs.110).aspx) as their common ancestor, so you can write a function that simply takes an instance of DbConnection and leave the rest of your code pretty much the same.

```
public bool CheckConnection(DbConnection connection) 
{
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        connection.Close();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // Le catch n'a pas de raison d'être, la variable étant à false par défaut.
    }

    return false;
}
```

You can then call your code using the same logic:

```
if (c.ConnectionString.Contains("metadata"))
{
    using (var connection = new EntityConnection(c.ConnectionString))
    {
        isWorking = CheckConnection(connection);
    }
}
else
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(c.ConnectionString))
    {
        isWorking = CheckConnection(connection);
    }
}
```

This is just a simple refactoring using what you already have without changing the logic of your code.

If you don't want to catch the generic exception (which in my opinion is completely fine in this case), C# 6 offers a new construct to allow catching certain exceptions more generically:

```
catch (Exception ex) when (ex is EntityException || ex is SqlException)           
{
    // exception handling code
}
```

Also, if there is no additional logic in your `if ... else` statement, you can use a single using block:

```
if (c.ConnectionString.Contains("metadata"))
{
    connection = new EntityConnection(c.ConnectionString);
}
else
{
    connection = new SqlConnection(c.ConnectionString);
}

using (connection)
{
    // same as before.
}
```

The next logical step would then be to make some sort of factory class / method that extracts and creates your different connections.

Comment: EntityException isn't a DbException though. On the other hand, just catching an `Exception` should be enough for this method

Comment: Yeah, already corrected before you commented ;) That was a mistake from not pasting the code again. You could also use the C# 6 `catch ... when` construct.

Comment: You could also use a single `connection` variable and a single `using`. Even if something happens between the variable assignment and the using block, an unopened connection object doesn't really need explicit disposal

Comment: You could. I'll add both our suggestions to the answer to stay within the context of the original question as we don't really have more context.

Comment: I'm just retrieving connections strings with `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` and using the code above to test each one.

Answer (score 2):

Since both are derived from `DbConnection`, you could do this:

```
using(DbConnection connection = c.ConnectionString.Contains("metadata") ? 
  new EntityConnection(c.ConnectionString) as DbConnection: new SqlConnection(c.ConnectionString) as DbConnection)
{
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        isWorking = true;
        connection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) //make this more generic
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

By making use of `DbConnection` (instead of individual Connection), you could test your connection.

Comment: It gaves me an error, "type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion"